# How to know or change the size of the Windows Event Log from a program under Windows XP?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, event-log

I ran into a weird problem on a Windows XP system. My local service app logs its diagnostic messages into the Windows Event Log, so at some point those messages stopped being logged. I thought that the issue was in my code, but then I discovered that other processes can't log messages either.

So I was wondering, is there a limit on the Windows Event Log size?

PS. I guess I need to write this specifically -- I need to know/change the size from a command line or an API.

Comment: I don't think there is such limit. How many events are there in the log? Also does this only happen for one provider or for all of them

Comment: This is off-topic here, however a simple Bing search gives this result http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748849.aspx

Comment: @Steve: Thanks. I don't use Bing :)

Comment: @Steve: Also, I need this for Windows XP and wevtutil is not supported there.

Comment: @izomorphius: Yes, there's a limit. Follow Steve's link... Now I need to find a way to change it from a program.

Comment: Change the title of your question before closing. Specify that you want to do this 'PROGRAMMATICALLY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit and behavior depends on the log configuration. Please check in the log properties if "When maximum log size is reached" is set to "Do not overwrite events". If so, the events will not be logged. You can set the limit there as well.

UPDATE: It turns out the question is how to check the behavior described above  programmatically. Please have a look at [EventLog.OverflowAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.overflowaction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [EventLog.MaximumKilobytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.maximumkilobytes%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [EventLog.MinimumRetentionDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.minimumretentiondays%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properties, that should be enough.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear from my original question -- I need this done from a command line or an API on a Windows XP system?

Comment: Yes, I thought the question was about why the events weren't logged and now the question is almost completely different.